# How to compose monadic functions/methods of type Function1 via 'andThen' in Scala?

Tags: scala, monads, function-composition

I'm trying to compose functions of types `f: a -> Either[_,b]` with each other but nothing seems to work. I tried extending `Function1` with implicits like below but keep getting compilation errors:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
object MyExtensions {
  implicit class AndThenEither[A,B](val e: Function1[A,Either[_,B]]) {
    def andThen[C](f:Function1[B, Either[_,C]]): Function1[A, Either[_,C]] = {
      (v1: A) => e.apply(v1).flatMap(b => f.apply(b)) //type: A => Either[_,C]
    }
  }
}
```

However the below fails:

```
object Sample extends App {

  case class TenX(t: Int)
  case class DoubleX(x: Int)

  def composeFunction1Test(): Unit = {
    val func1: (Int) => Either[String, TenX] = (i: Int) => Right(TenX(10 * i))
    val func2: (TenX) => Either[String, DoubleX] = (t: TenX) => Right(DoubleX(t.t * 2))

    val pipeline = func1 andThen func2 

    val result = pipeline(1); //Expected Right(DoubleX(20))
  }
}
```

This keeps complaining about a type mismatch and I can't figure out what's wrong. Also, if I try to use it with `def` defined methods (instead of `val` like above) it still fails compilation.

**Question:** How can I compose such `Either` typed functions with an equivalent `andThen` operator/function to be used across any such function or class method to allow for such chaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `andThen` is already defined on `Function1` then implicit resolution will not kick in to resolve extension method of the same name. Try renaming the extension method

```
implicit class AndThenEither ... {
    def fooAndThen ...
  }

func1 fooAndThen func2 // should work
```

[Kleisli](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html) is indeed a way of composing functions returning monadic value.